# How to create a master controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We have a case where a controller must always be executed in every request to set some default values in the model next we execute the required controller. How to set a master controller to be always executed including other controller in the same request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a base controller class, with a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method which getscalled on every request, before an actual handler method, e.g

```
@ModelAttribute
public void everyRequest(WebRequest request, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("default", true);
}
```

all thats left is to extend this base controller class from your actual controllers

If you're using Spring 4.x, a better approach is to use a `@ControllerAdvice` which assist all, or a selected group of components and can be used for either adding the model attribute, apply common init binding or error handling. An example

```
@ControllerAdvice
class Advice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void everyRequest(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("default", true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring [HandlerInterceptor #preHandle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-), it provides you access to the `Handler` which may be useful and also provides you with the power to exclude calling of some of the `controllers`.

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/admin/**"/>
    <bean class="com.test.yourInterceptorClass" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```